# list.remove() em uma linha

Tags: python

tenho a list:

```
lista = ['', 'a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '', '', ' ']
```

e dela estou tentando remover os item em branco: `['']` ou `[' ']` logo tenho o seguinte código:

```
if(ret_b == [' ']):
    ret_b.clear()
```

minha duvida é: Consigo fazer isso em uma linha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você não se importa em gerar uma nova lista com os resultados, pode fazer:

```
>>> [elemento for elemento in lista if elemento.strip() != ""]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Caso você tenha certeza que sua lista só contém strings (e vale lembrar que é uma boa prática não misturar tipos diferentes em listas), então pode fazer de forma mais simples:

```
>>> [elemento for elemento in lista if elemento.strip()]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Isso funciona porque strings vazias são avaliadas como `False` quando usadas em um contexto que pede um valor booleano. Mas, como outras coisas que não são strings vazias também são avaliadas como `False`, só use se tiver certeza que todos os elementos são strings.

Comment: A resposta está correta, no entanto é desnecessário a parte ` != ""` na expressão `if` - strigns vazias em Python já tem valro booleano falso, portanto só é necessário: `[elemento for elemento in lista if elemento.strip()]` - se o método `strip()` retornar uma strign vazia, seu valor booleano é falso, e o `if`filtra esse elemento da lista final.

Comment: @jsbueno Foi o que eu disse, ué. :)

Comment: a é,,na segunda metade da resposta.  foi mesmo. Desculpa.  é que andeilendo umas respostas não Pythonicas por aí e entrei no modo automático de "comentar o jeito certo".

Comment: @jsbueno Sem problemas. :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) e aplicar uma expressão lambda para remover os espaços em brancos e também as strings vazias:

```
lista = filter(lambda item: item != ' ' and item != '', lista)
```

Saída:

> ['a', 'b', 'c']